# What is the right way to remove large switch from my jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, tags, factory

What is the right way to remove switch from my JSP file? I have a factory which can return multiple types of objects. Each of them has its own representation logic, so I need something like this:

```
//From controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/source", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView doMainJob(@RequestParam("text") String text) {
    ResultState state = new ResultStateFactory().fromString(text);
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("result/view");
    model.addObject("state", state);
    model.addObject("stateType", state.getClass());
    return model;
}

//from jsp/result/view.jsp
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="main"  tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="r"  tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/result" %>
<main:basic_layout>
  <jsp:body>
    <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${stateType == StateA}"><r:stateA param=${state} /></c:when>
      <c:when test="${stateType == StateB}"><r:stateB param=${state} /></c:when>
      <c:when test="${stateType == StateC}"><r:stateC param=${state} /></c:when>
      .
      .
      .
      <c:when test="${stateType == StateX}"><r:stateX param=${state} /></c:when>
      <c:when test="${stateType == StateY}"><r:stateY param=${state} /></c:when>
    </c:choose>
  </jsp:body>
</main:basic_layout>
```

My factory is based on annotations, so I can easily add state with the correct annotation. I want to do something similar to tag views. It would be ideal if I add just 2 files: 1 state with correct annotation and 1 tag file.

Comment: Why don't you create a single `<r:state type="${stateType}" param="${state}">` which delegates under the hoods further to the right implementation?

Comment: Wouldn't `ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("result/view/" + state.getClass().getSimpleName());` work also?

Comment: `ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("result/view/" + state.getClass().getSimpleName());`  would work, but what if i need to show list of results

Answer (score 1):

Put the `sateType` into the tag result:

```
<r:state param=${state} type="${stateType}" />
```